# how export graph from jsp page to excel page

Tags: java, excel, charts

HI, I am displaying the graph on my jsp page and also data in grid below the graph, now I want to export the graph with data to the excel sheet. in excel the data will display in below hte graph in a grid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download and add this library to your classpath 
jexcelapi.sourceforge.net

You should look at this example
[reading and writing excel documents in Java](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html#createexcel)

In your jsp page you can have a button that triggers a servlet. The servlet will then kick off the script above and respond to the browser.

[servlet for creating excel documents](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jexcel/how-do-i-output-an-excel-file-from-a-servlet.html)

Basically - you need to pass the data to the servlet and let the servlet build the excel document then send it to the user via the HttpServletResponse.

Good luck